# Oracle: split and join the splited elements

Tags: sql, oracle

For example, I have a strings like this

```
this is test string1
this is another test string2
this is another another test string3
```

I need to split the strings by space, then join all the elements except last two. So the output should look like this

```
this is 
this is another 
this is another another
```

Answer (score 2):

`Regexp_Replace()` should do the job here:

```
regexp_replace(yourcolumn, ' [^ ]* [^ ]*$','')
```

[SQLFiddle of this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/782ed/2) (Oracle isn't working on sqlfiddle today, so this is postgres; but their implementation of regexp_replace is nearly the same, and for this example it's exactly the same)

```
CREATE TABLE test(f1 VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
  ('this is another another test string3'),
  ('this is test string1'),
  ('this is another test string2');

SELECT regexp_replace(f1, ' [^ ]* [^ ]*$','') FROM test;

+-------------------------+
|     regexp_replace      |
+-------------------------+
| this is another another |
| this is                 |
| this is another         |
+-------------------------+
```

The regex string here `' [^ ]* [^ ]*$'` says to find a space, followed by any number of non-space characters `[^ ]*` followed by another space, followed by any number of non-space characters `[^ ]*`, followed by the end of the string `$` which we just replace out with nothing `''`.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach could be without regular expressions, longer to type, but faster to execute; it mainly depends on what you need.

It's not completely clear what to do if the input string has less than 3 tokens, so this is a way to handle different needs:

```
select str,
       case when instr(str, ' ', 1, 2) != 0 then 
        substr(str, 1, instr(str, ' ', -1, 2)-1)
       else
        str
       end as res1,
       substr(str, 1, instr(str, ' ', -1, 2)-1) as res2
from (
    select 'this' str from dual union all
    select 'this is' str from dual union all
    select 'this is test' str from dual union all
    select 'this is test string1' str from dual union all
    select 'this is another test string2' str from dual union all
    select 'this is another another test string3' str from dual
)

STR                                  RES1                                 RES2
------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
this                                 this
this is                              this is
this is test                         this                                 this
this is test string1                 this is                              this is
this is another test string2         this is another                      this is another
this is another another test string3 this is another another              this is another another
```